# Unexpected token "in" in ForEach-Object

Tags: powershell-2.0

Looking for the proper formatting for this `ForEach-Object`. I am going through a book on intro to PowerShell. One example from the book is as follows, but the example does not work.

```
$TEXTfile = $other = 0
ForEach-Object ($file in (Get-Childitem C:\PSLearn) {
  switch ($file.extension) {
    ".txt"  {$TEXTfile++}
    default {$other++}
  }
}
#Display results
"$TEXTfile text files"
"$other other files"
```

Error returned is:

> Unexpected token 'in' in expression or statement.

What is the proper formatting for `(<name> in <collection>)` section?

The opening paren `(` before `$file` seems wrong to me, because I don't see the matching close paren `)`, but that is exactly the example in the book.

Comment: If that example really is literally copied from a book: throw the book away. The author obviously didn't understand the difference between `foreach` and `ForEach-Object`. And if this mistake made it into the book I wouldn't be surprised if there were other glaring issues as well.

Answer (score 2):

`foreach` and `ForEach-Object` are [different loop constructs](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/07/08/getting-to-know-foreach-and-foreach-object.aspx). The latter is for processing pipeline input, the former is for iterating over a list and can't read from or write to pipelines (workarounds notwithstanding).

A `foreach` loop looks like this:

```
foreach ($item in $list) {
  # do stuff with $item
}
```

whereas a `ForEach-Object` loop usually looks like this:

```
... | ForEach-Object {
  # do stuff with current object variable $_
} | ...
```

You can emulate `foreach` loops with `ForEach-Object` loops to some extent, though:

```
ForEach-Object -InputObject $list {
  # do stuff with $_
}
```

The loop variable, however, remains the "current object" [automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) (`$_`).

Comment: Thank you for the instruction.  I appreciate your time.

Comment: Why is `foreach` an alias of `foreach-object` ?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$TEXTfile = $other = 0
ForEach ($file in Get-ChildItem  C:\temp){
     switch ($file.extension) {
    ".txt"  {$TEXTfile++}
    default {$other++} } }
 #Display results
 "$TEXTfile text files"
 "$other other files"
```

Comment: Thanks for the example onskee